# Is there a way in Quicksight to set dynamic titles on the visuals?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a requirement to translate our Quicksight dashboard.

We are currently configured a "language" parameter which contains the language user desired to see the dashboard in. We are using this parameter to filter the data in our data set which has rows for each available language. This works well for the data display in our visuals on the dashboard.

The problem I have is regarding the titles and labels on the visuals. I'd like these to be updated depending on the language parameter as well. I've found you can template the title, i.e., `<<$language>>` to include the parameter, but I can't find anyway to "lookup" the desired value using the parameter as a key.

I've looked at calculated fields which can be determined using parameters, but unfortunately you can't template titles/labels with them.

The only option I've considered at this point is having to duplicate the dashboard in every single language supported and then routing the users to the correct dashboard.

Does anyone else have any other ideas?